# Rerun failed tests with TestNG

Tags: automated-testing, java, testng

I recently migrate from Junit to TestNg. Currently, I try to understand how to rerun the failed test.

According, I've just to run my test suite then recall TestNG with the testng-failed file. Easy.

But, here my experience. I ask to TestNG to run only one class, with 5 tests where one is KO.

Now see my testng-failed.xml files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="3" verbose="0" name="Failed suite [Surefire suite]">
  <test name="Surefire test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.corp.qa.spec.TestLogin"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Surefire test -->
  <test name="Surefire test(failed)">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.corp.qa.spec.TestLogin">
        <methods>
          <include name="openLoginPage"/>
          <include name="die"/>
          <include name="loginAsManager"/>
        </methods>
      </class> <!-- com.corp.qa.spec.TestLogin -->
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Surefire test(failed) -->
</suite> <!-- Failed suite [Surefire suite] -->
```

TestNG create a test suite where the whole class will be run, then the @BeforeMethod (openLoginPage), the @AfterMethod (die), and finally the failing method.

I missed something? I expected to only see

```
    <classes>
      <class name="com.corp.qa.spec.TestLogin">
        <methods>
          <include name="loginAsManager"/>
        </methods>
      </class> <!-- com.corp.qa.spec.TestLogin -->
```

Edit: After updating TestNG to 6.9.12, failed tests file is correcly set.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="1" verbose="0" name="Failed suite [Surefire suite]">
  <test name="Surefire test(failed)">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.corp.qa.spec.TestLogin">
        <methods>
          <include name="die"/>
          <include name="openLoginPage"/>
          <include name="loginAsManager"/>
        </methods>
      </class> <!-- com.corp.qa.spec.TestLogin -->
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Surefire test(failed) -->
</suite> <!-- Failed suite [Surefire suite] -->
```

Comment: Thanks man! one more addition - still feeling fixed is not perfectly tuned. Expecting one more update. Lets see !

Comment: Why do you mean by feeling is not perfectly tuned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can run only failed test cases explicitly without any code**. This can be easily done by *running one simple testng-failed.xml*

**Steps:**

1. If your test cases are failing then once all test suite completed then you have to refresh your project .

   - **Right click on project**
   - **Click on refresh** or
   - Select project and press f5.
2. Check **test-output folder**,

   - at last, **you will get testng-failed.xml**
3. Now simply **run testng-failed.xml**

**Updated after knowing version used is 6.9.10**

- Version you are using is having open issues
- Due to that issue testng-failed.xml itself is not generated properly

**Work around -**

1. Can you try 6.9.11-SNAPSHOT? Its working for me
2. You can force your TestNG eclipse plugin to start using the TestNG jar available in your CLASSPATH by doing the following :

   - Project > Properties > TestNG > Use project testng jar
3. Uncheck that option & run the tests with 6.9.11-SNAPSHOT in my pom.xml

Please crosscheck once. Hope it helps you!

Comment: It's exactly what I did. My issue is this testng-failed.xml is not properly created. Look at it.

Comment: Are you using TestNG 6.3.1?

Comment: Yes the latest.

Comment: This is not the latest one - can you share your TestNG version? Its lot related to version & answer could differ for different version

Comment: Sorry, I answered too quickly. I use the 6.9.10 version.

Comment: no problem. I have updated my answer :)

Comment: Oh I didn't know there was a new release. On the maven repository, the latest is 6.9.10. I checked on the official website, and saw I have to use the http://jcenter.bintray.com repository. I will update the version, and comeback to tell you if it's work fine.

Comment: That would be great

Comment: The testng-failed.xml files is now well formatted. TestNG does not add the full class.
But do you know why I can still see the before and after hooks (loginAsManager and die) and not just only the test method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43678/discussion-between-tetienne-and-narendrac).